# String match version format

Tags: regex, bash

I want to let users select multiple layers of folders.

Once they select a version folder (Folder name similar as: 1.0.0) I will continue to do next steps.

How can I match the format like 1.0.0?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use regular expressions:

```
folderName="1.2.3";
matchPattern="^[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]$";

# if regex match, execute the command after "&&"
[[ $folderName =~ $matchPattern ]] && echo "Folder name matches pattern"
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try the below command.

```
grep -Po '(?foldername)\d.\d.\d'
```